# Setting selected option in laravel form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to give selected value like this html:

```
<select name="myselect" id="myselect">
 <option value="1">Item 1</option>
 <option value="2" selected='selected'>Item 2</option>
```

how can I achieve this, with laravel forms?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use this package and check the docs:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#drop-down-lists

form you html , you need use this mark

```
{!! Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S'); !!}
```

Comment: Laravel Collective has been discontinued :(

Comment: The HTML package is still maintained though…
https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/issues/600

Comment: The HTML package and the Remote package are still supported.

Answer (score 71):

Everybody talking about you go using `{!! Form::select() !!}` 
but, if all you need is to use plain simple HTML.. here is another way to do it.

```
<select name="myselect">
@foreach ($options as $key => $value)
    <option value="{{ $key }}"
    @if ($key == old('myselect', $model->option))
        selected="selected"
    @endif
    >{{ $value }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

the `old()` function is useful when you submit the form and the validation fails. So that, `old()` returns the previously selected value.

Answer (score 27):

You can do it like this.

```
<select class="form-control" name="resoureceName">

  <option>Select Item</option>

  @foreach ($items as $item)
    <option value="{{ $item->id }}" {{ ( $item->id == $existingRecordId) ? 'selected' : '' }}> {{ $item->name }} </option>
  @endforeach    </select>
```

Comment: elegant answer.

Comment: simple and useful

Answer (score 15):

You have to set the default option by passing a third argument.

```
{{ Form::select('myselect', [1, 2], 2, ['id' => 'myselect']) }}
```

You can read the documentation **[here.](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists)**

Comment: that's for Laravel 4.2 .. If you want to use `Form::select` on Laravel 5.1+ you need to pull in `laravelcollective/html` package

Comment: what if it was a multi select where multiple items are checked?  i have a multi-select with checkboxes, see `multiselect-ui`

Answer (score 11):

**Another ordinary simple way** this is good if there are few options in select box

```
<select name="job_status">
   <option {{old('job_status',$profile->job_status)=="unemployed"? 'selected':''}}  value="unemployed">Unemployed</option>
   <option {{old('job_status',$profile->job_status)=="employed"? 'selected':''}} value="employed">Employed</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

Laravel 9:

```
@php
    $item=2;
@endphp

<select name="myselect" id="myselect">
 <option value="1">Item 1</option>
 <option value="2" @selected($item == 2) >Item 2</option>
</select>
```

[Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases#checked-selected-blade-directives)

Answer (score 5):

Setting selected option is very simple in laravel form :

```
{{ Form::select('number', [0, 1, 2], 2) }}
```

Output will be :

```
<select name="number">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you answered same answer as @chonchol about 2 hrs later?  i would poin tit, but i pointed first to answer.  or did somebody edit theirs?

Answer (score 5):

```
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
             <option value="{{$category->id}}" 
               @foreach ($posts->postRelateToCategory as $Postcategory)
                 @if ($Postcategory->id == $category->id)
                 {{'selected="selected"'}}
                 @endif 
               @endforeach >
              {{ $category->category_name }} </option>               
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  <?php
      $items = DB::table('course')->get()->pluck('name','id');
      $selectID = 3;
  ?>

  <div class="form-group">
   {{ Form::label('course_title', 'Course Title') }}
   {!! Form::select('myselect', $items, $select, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  </div>
```

This show similar types of following options :

```
<select name="myselect" id="myselect">
 <option value="1">Computer Introduction</option>
 <option value="2">Machine Learning</option>
 <option value="3" selected='selected'>Python Programming</option>
 <option value="4">Networking Fundamentals</option>
 .
 .
 .
 .  
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
<select class="form-control" name="country_code" value="{{ old('country_code') }}">
   @foreach (\App\SystemCountry::orderBy('country')->get() as $country)
       <option value="{{ $country->country_code }}"
           @if ($country->country_code == "LKA")
             {{'selected="selected"'}}
           @endif
       >
          {{ $country->country }}
       </option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details

Answer (score 3):

To echo some other answers here, the code I just used with 5.6 is this

```
{{ Form::select('status', ['Draft' => 'Draft', 'Sent' => 'Sent', 'Paid' => 'Paid'], $model->status, ['id' => 'status']) }}
```

In order to be able to use the Form Helper from LaravelCollective I took a look at https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#drop-down-lists

I also had to composer require the dependency also so that I could use it in my projects

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5"
```

Lastly I altered my `config/app.php` and added the following in the `$aliases` array

```
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
```

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html should be consulted if any of the above ceases to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an **Eloquent Relationship** between your models you can do something like that:

```
@foreach ($ships as  $ship)
<select name="data[]" class="form-control" multiple>
    @foreach ($goods_containers as  $container)
        <option value="{{ $container->id }}"
                @if ($ship->containers->contains('container_id',$container->id ) ))
                selected="selected"
                @endif
        >{{ $container->number}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Simply paste this code you will get the desired output that you needed.

```
 {{ Form::select ('myselect', ['1' => 'Item 1', '2' => 'Item 2'], 2 , ['id' =>'myselect']) }}` `
```

Comment: Just Simply paste this code you will get the desired output that you needed.

Comment: Thanks Ashish making the code on proper indentation i am new to stackoverflow. any ways  i think this code will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this for limited options:

```
          <select class="form-control required" id="assignedRole">
            <option id = "employeeRole" selected ="@if($employee->employee_role=='Employee'){'selected'}else{''} @endif">Employee</option>
            <option id = "adminRole" selected ="@if($employee->employee_role=='Admin'){'selected'}else{''} @endif">Admin</option>
            <option id = "employerRole" selected ="@if($employee->employee_role=='Employer'){'selected'}else{''} @endif">Employer</option>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still here, here is my simple version.

```
<select name="status" class="js-example-basic-single w-100">
              <option value="" @if($brand->status == '') ? selected : null @endif disabled>Choose what to be seen on brand section</option>
              <option value="TA" @if($brand->status == 'TA') ? selected : null @endif>Title Active</option>
              <option value="ITA" @if($brand->status == 'ITA') ? selected : null @endif>Image Title Active</option>
             
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the shortest code

```
<select class="form-control" name="country_code">
    @foreach (\App\SystemCountry::orderBy('country')->get() as $country)
       <option value="{{ $country->country_code }}"
           @if ($country->country_code == "LKA") selected="selected" @endif >{{ $country->country }}
       </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have laravel form use simpe {{ }}

```
<option value="days" {{ $generaltask->frequency === "days" ? "selected" : "" }}>Days</option>
```