# display fetch data in dropdown menu with "where" value selected in laravel

Tags: laravel, dropdown

I am trying to display the currencies in the dropdown menu but I need the data with a value of default=1 to be selected. upon searching, i found a sample and tried to applied it to my controller, here's what I came up,

```
$currencies = \DB::table('currencies')->where('default', 1)->lists('acronym');
```

it doesn't work. the error message said

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()
```

also I read a comment that the list() is already obsolete in laravel.

how can I achieve this?

**here's from my create function in controller**

```
public function create()
{
    $currencies = \DB::table('currencies')->where('default', 1)->lists('acronym');
    return view ('orders.create')->with('currencies', $currencies);
}
```

**here's from create blade**

```
{{ Form::select('currency_id', $currencies, Input::old('currency_id'),null, ['class' => 'form-control input-lg','required']) }}
```

thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ->pluck(),

```
$currencies = \DB::table('currencies')->pluck('currency_name','id');

// In blade
{{ Form::select('currency_id', $currencies, null, ['class' => 'form-control input-lg','required']) }}
```

Read more about pluck [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck).

Comment: thanks @ViperTecPro! may I ask how am I going to display the data in the select field with the value of default=1 being selected?

Comment: Don't worry about that laravel collective does that for you just remove Input::old('currency_id') from the select,

Comment: it does show the data but only the value with default=1. what I would like to do is to show also the other data. which means the data with value of default=0. how can I make it possible? thanks!

Comment: If you want both default 0 and 1 then remove where clause from the query

Comment: yes I removed it already. so currently all the data is now in the dropdown. how can i make the default=1 being selected?

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/38428324/5928015 i think you're problem will definitely resolved by this