# How to load data in text fields dynamically when selecting an option from drop down which is populated from database? Laravel Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

**Simply speaking I have Added a drop down in my form which has loaded values from the database.The Form consists of input fields. Some fields already have values in database which I want to load using drop down so that user may not enter them again.**
Here is the HTML view for drop down:

```
<select sku=""  id="sku_drop" class="selectpicker" data-size="7" data-style="btn btn-success btn-round" name="sku_drop" title="Select SKU">
    <option value="0" disabled>Select SKU</option>
    @foreach ($sku as $item)
        <option value="{{$item->sku}}">{{$item->sku}}</option>    
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**This drop down has some values, when user selects a certain value, the form must be auto filled from the database.
I have not made any function in my controller or any route for this procedure.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting selected option in laravel form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428324/setting-selected-option-in-laravel-form)

Comment: What means *"must be autofilled from database"*. You asked half question not providing the minimal details besides the way you create your option elements. Please [edit].

Answer (score 0):

To load some other fields based on selection of select box you will need javascript for that (or jQuery).

something like this:

```js
const selectBox = document.getElementById('select-box');
const textField = document.getElementById('text_field');

selectBox.addEventListener('change', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  textField.value = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-box">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<label for="text_field">Text Field:</label>
<input id="text_field" type="text" name="text_field">
```

Comment: how can i do this with onchange event on drop down and ajax?