# Laravel Form Set Default Selection

Tags: php, laravel, forms, null

If I make a change in the code I shared, I want it to come directly with 'Produits' selected or is there an easier alternative?

I would be very grateful if you can help me with this.
Thank you for your help.

[image: img]

```
@section('page-action')
    <div class="col-auto" style="width: 200px;">
        {{ Form::select('item_type', $product_type, null, ['id' => 'item_type', 'class' => 'form-control select ', 'required' => 'required', 'placeholder' => 'Type de produit']) }}
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting selected option in laravel form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428324/setting-selected-option-in-laravel-form)

Comment: Welcome to SO ... if you make a change to what code? ... and you want it to always have 'Produits' selected?